# how to setState object inside array in the state

Tags: reactjs

i have an array of objects called `messagesObj` and i am trying to `setState` the content in `messagesObj` and nothing worked.

```
this.state = {
    messagesObj:[{
        name:"",
        time:"",
        content:""
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example? And also, why do you have an array with a single object?  Are you expecting there to be multiple objects in `messagesObj` or should it not be an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can set state of messageObj using spread operator like this

using spread operator

```
this.setState({
  messagesObj: [
    ...this.state.messagesObj,
    content: "your content"
  ]
})
```

Please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: what is this.state.name where does it come from?

Comment: why? all he wants is to set an object in messagesObj... you are just confusing him even more